# How to access the multifarm GUI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

I've build a multifarm:
[image: multifarm]

However, when I right click the farm blocks no GUI appears... So how do I access it?

Comment: I've proposed an edit to add the [[tag:minecraft-forestry]] tag to this question, since I presume that's the mod the multifarms are from in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dirt, the farm places humus itself.

The farm also has to be exactly four blocks high. The horizontal size depends on the size of your multifarm. All possible options can be found [here](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:structure).

Keep in mind that you have to  constantly supply power and must regularly insert water, dirt and fertilizer. For maximum effiency it's best to build the stone bricks higher up against the farm center (*not* above the center though), so your machines for input/output of resources don't hinder treegrowth.

Comment: Now I have removed the dirt, but I still can't access the interface...

Comment: @Andalur Is your centerpiece the correct size and height? see [here](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:structure) for more information about correct sizes.

Comment: Yes, the blocks are 5x5 and the total diameter is 17x17.

Comment: Uhm, I forgot the right height... This was the error.